# Getting expo-token from logged in user

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, token

I am building my first multiuser react-native app with Expo and I am trying to set up notifications. In order to do that, I need to get the expo-token from a user. The way I logged in users is with AsyncStorage. How can I get the expo-token from a logged-in user so that I will send a user a notification once a different user makes an action?